# Unpairing Apple Watch from iPhone causes loss of HealthKit data?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

A few weeks ago I had an Apple Watch for a development project. I collected some HealthData with it which was stored on my connected iPhone. After unpairing both devices the COMPLETE HealthKit data was lost. I didn't know about this beforehand and was quite upset.

Now a friend has the same Apple Watch for the same development project paired to his iPhone. We need to unpair them again but can not afford to loose the collected HealthKit data.

What's the best solution here? Why did we even loose data in the first place? Is there any way to avoid this without needing to backup to iCloud or anything similar?

Comment: Did you try backing up before you unpaired? and when you re-pair again did you restore from a backup that is listed in the Apple watch.

Comment: @satheeshwaran: No, i did not backup because i didn't know it would appearently delete all my data! And i never did repear because this was just for a development project.

Comment: but iOS and watchOS by default take a back up please check again when repairing.

Comment: When you do a backup, make sure it is an iTunes encrypted backup. Health data does not get backed up to iCloud.

Comment: That's not expected behavior.  You should file a bug with Apple.